# Using the phabricator API to create maniphest task with javascript

Tags: javascript, phabricator

Long story short, after many trial and errors, I came down to this and still getting an error ***“transactions” is not a list of transactions***. What is wrong with this payload? There isn't a clear documentation so anyone had done this successfully?

```
var payload = {
“api.token”: PHAB_TOKEN,
transactions: [{“type”: “title”, “value”: “test”}],
output: ‘json’
};

var options = {
method: ‘post’,
payload: payload,
};

var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(“https://xxxxxxx/api/maniphest.edit”, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for this. The phab token should be under a key named "__conduit__", like below.

```
  var payload = {
    "params": JSON.stringify({
      "__conduit__": { token: PHAB_TOKEN },
      transactions: [{“type”: “title”, “value”: “test”}],
    }),
    output: 'json'
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: payload,
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://xxxxxxxx/api/maniphest.edit", options);
```